# Django - CreateView /Modelform wont save Many to Many

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm having trouble with the following problem: 
I am working on simple database app where users can add both Objects and create 'Notes' for these objects. 
These notes in turn can have tags (a many to many) which can be used to filter them.

However, when I am creating a new Note, the accompanying tags are not saved in the form.

Here is the code I used for the Noteform

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
      model = Note
      fields = ['content', 'tags']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
      self.app = kwargs.pop('app')
      self.key = kwargs.pop('model_pk')
      self.model_object = apps.get_model(self.app, self.model)
      self.linked_object = self.model_object.objects.get(pk=self.key)
      super(NoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


  def save(self, commit=True):
      note = super(NoteForm, self).save(commit=False)
      note.content_object = self.linked_object
      if commit:
          note.save()
      return note
```

And here is the accompanying view:

```
class BaseNoteCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  login_url = '/login/'
  form_class = NoteForm

def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(BaseNoteCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs['model'] = self.kwargs['model']
      kwargs['app'] = self.kwargs['app']
      kwargs['model_pk'] = self.kwargs['model_pk']
      return kwargs

def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.user = self.request.user
      return super().form_valid(form)
```

Now I read that I might have to use the save_m2m() method. However, whenever I include it into the form or the view I run into the

```
'NoteForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'
```

error.

When I print the 'kwargs' in the form, I see that the tags are including in the post

```
{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'data': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['EOWT03UtSdFdJ9H2qD0oKYvv8GZy8ZvWTBRRTV3JBRuULuDcaQH4dWgC2S2bUYJS'], 'content': ['okj'], 'tags': ['2', '3']}>, 'files': <MultiValueDict: {}>, 'instance': None, 'model': 'book', 'app': 'source_tracker', 'model_pk': '1'}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and why both the tags arent saved and the `save_m2m()` method triggers an error?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit: I've included the 'Note' (and the Tag) models below, as requested**

```
 class Tag(models.Model):
      added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
      notes = GenericRelation('Note', blank=True, null=True, 
      related_name='notes')
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name



 class Note(models.Model):
      added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      content = models.TextField()
      content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
      object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
      tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, 
      related_name='note_tags')
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.content[:30]
```

Comment: Please show the Note model. What kind of fields are `content_object` and `tags`? Also, you would probably be better doing all that logic in `form_valid` rather than the form save, which would prevent you from having to pass it all in to the form.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've included both the Note and the Tag model. 

The content_object refers to a generic relationship with either a 'Book', 'Article' and 'Pamphlet' object (the app creates a bibliography for historical research)